# Problem using read() to write contents of file to screen and to other file in C

Tags: c, linux, file, operating-system

I am trying to copy a file's contents to another file. I also want to display the file's contents to the screen, and I want to do all this using system calls (write) if possible.

This is my code

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define PERMS 0644

char *workfile = "file1.txt";
char *workfile2 = "file2.txt";
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int fd2;
    int fd3;
    ssize_t nread0;
    ssize_t nread;
    char buf[1024];
    char buf2[1024];
    ssize_t nread2;

    const char msg[] = "File 3 contains:";
    if ((fd= open(workfile, O_RDWR,PERMS)) == -1) {
        printf("Couldn't open %s\n", workfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fd2 = open(workfile2,O_RDWR,PERMS)) == -1) {
        printf("Couldn't open %s\n",workfile2);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (nread =read(fd,buf,1024)) {
        if (lseek(fd2,0,SEEK_END) < 0) return 1;
        if (write(fd,buf,nread) && write(1,buf,nread) < nread) {
            close(fd);
            close(fd2);
            return(-3);
        }
    }

    close(fd);
    if (nread ==-1) {
        return (-4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to write to the screen as well, the contents of `file1` are not copied to `file2` but the contents of `file1` are written to the screen.

I have also tried adding the `read` and `write` outside the `while` loop with its separate buffer and `ssize_t`.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: Pay close attention to the descriptors you're writing to. (Also: Use more appropriate open modes intstead of `O_RDWR` and always check the return value of `write()` and other functions for errors)

Comment: `read` can return a negative number on error, the check should be `(nread = read(...)) > 0`

Comment: In case my now deleted comment was read... I read up on it and noticed that I mixed up two different languages.... I think somebody pointed it out to me in a now also deleted comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line I think you want `fd2` to write to the copy file.

Also note operator precedence, `<` has a higher precedence than `&&`. Wrap the write calls in parentheses to evaluate these before comparing with the `<` operator.

```
   if((write(fd2,buf,nread) && write(1,buf,nread)) < nread )
```